# Is the term “Followers of The Way” related to Taoism?

Tags: life-of-jesus, early-church, etymology, spiritual-theology, asia

I read that some early Christians were called “Followers of The Way”.  I also know that The Tao (of Taoism) is often translated as “The Way”.

Is there any connection either etymologically or in the roots of the two systems?

*I thought of this because I have heard theories that Jesus may have traveled eastward during his mostly unaccounted-for younger years (his twenties I think it would be roughly).*

Comment: Since Christianity Stack Exchange is about Christianity, it is only reasonable to expect that you provide evidence of research you have already conducted to show where or why or when the Tao "is often translated as The Way".  I do not feel inclined to do research into Taoism in order to find out the who, the why or the where of such a claim.

Answer (score 1):

**Religion and Philosophy** It is true that Christians were called followers of **the Way**. This is with the understanding that Jesus is "The Way, the Truth, and the Life." And with the realization that Jesus claimed--and is--Deity. He was the Messiah prophesied about by the Abrahamic, monotheistic Covenant of Jehovah God.

On the other hand, **Taoism** believes in no God, but is a philosophic worldview concerning the transformation of physical beings becoming part of the universe. It is an Eastern philosophy that could not be farther from Christian beliefs!

The **rumors** that Jesus traveled to the East are just that: unsubstantiated rumors---and deserve no intelligent consideration. The "Silent Years" of Jesus are just that: **silent**.

Keep reading the Gospels of Jesus, and you will see the superiority of His teaching about Life: a Way that leads to heaven and Eternal Life in the Presence of a personal God. Peace!